# I am getting error: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting error:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
    It will be removed at the end of 2018.
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your library project, replace `compile` with `implementation`

Comment: Yes this should work. This issue is so simple, it makes me wonder why the gradle file can't be converted automatically.

Comment: I am trying that one also but that package is missing error showing please help.

Comment: show your error

Comment: @Narasimham update your question with project-level `build.gradle`